# How do I re-format this DF into the desired output?

Tags: r, format

I have a DF with several variables. Each variable has 3 trials for each date. In some cases, there were 6 trials for the variable on a specified date. See link to DF as a .csv in Github

https://github.com/michaeldavies64/Test_data/blob/main/Test_Data.csv

I wish to put it into this format:

```
Dates<-c("29/11/2020","29/11/2020","29/11/2020","20/11/2020","20/11/2020","20/11/2020","20/11/2020","20/11/2020","20/11/2020","10/11/2020","10/11/2020","10/11/2020","10/11/2020","10/11/2020","10/11/2020")
V_1<- c("48.2","45.9","48.2","47.1","46.5","45.8","44.7","47.6","47.1","47.1","46.4","46.7","45.0","46.5","47.1")
V_2<- c("3.07","3.01", "3.00","3.04","3.00","3.00", "3.02","3.06","3.06","3.04","3.01","3.00","3.00","3.07","3.06")
Test2<- cbind(Dates,V_1,V_2)
```

I am new to R and I am unsure how to mutate the DF into this format.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you have data in this format? What you have is matrix and all the numbers have turned into characters in there.

Comment: @RonakShah See edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a base R option using `reshape`

```
nm <- names(Test[-1])
out <- cbind(Test[-1, ][1], setNames(Test[-1, -1], ave(nm, gsub("\\..*", "", nm), FUN = function(x) paste0(gsub("\\..*", "", x), ".", seq_along(x)))))
z <- subset(
  `row.names<-`(
    (u <- reshape(
      cbind(q = 1:nrow(out), out),
      direction = "long",
      idvar = c("Dates", "q"),
      varying = -(1:2)
    ))[with(u, order(q, time)), ],
    NULL
  ),
  select = -c(q, time)
)
```

which gives

```
> z
        Dates   V_1  V_2
1  29/11/2020  48.2 3.07
2  29/11/2020  45.9 3.01
3  29/11/2020  48.2 3.00
4  20/11/2020  47.1 3.04
5  20/11/2020  46.5 3.00
6  20/11/2020  45.8 3.00
7  20/11/2020  44.7 3.02
8  20/11/2020  47.6 3.06
9  20/11/2020  47.1 3.06
10 10/11/2020  47.1 3.04
11 10/11/2020  46.4 3.06
12 10/11/2020  46.7 3.00
13 10/11/2020  45.0 3.00
14 10/11/2020  46.5 3.07
15 10/11/2020  47.1 3.06
```

Comment: Hi Thomas, the solution you have suggested doesn't follow my required format. If there were 3 trials on a specific date then I wish to have all three trials still present. Your solutions looks as though it removes the 2nd and 3rd trials?

Comment: @MichaelD I updated my solution so `z` is identical to `Test2`.

Comment: That works now, thank you! I had shortened the example to just 2 variables whereas I actually have 34. Where would I need to change the code to adjust for this?

Comment: @MichaelD I don't think you need to change if you just have more variables but with the same format in your post

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
# remove first row from Test which contains the "Trial#" designations
Test[-1,] %>% 
  # turn it into a tibble
  as_tibble() %>% 
  # make an observation indicator
  mutate(obs = 1:n()) %>% 
  # for the pivoting to work, you need to have a searchable pattern 
  # so I make V_1 into V_1.0 and V_2 into V_2.0 to match the way the 
  # other variables are made
  rename("V_1.0" = "V_1", 
         "V_2.0" = "V_2") %>% 
  # pivot the data to long-form from wide-form.  The names_pattern argument
  # tells it to search for two things separated by a period and to split
  # that into two variables named "var" and "num". 
  pivot_longer(-c(Dates, obs), names_pattern="(.*)\\.(.*)", names_to=c("var", "num"), values_to="val") %>% 
  # trim the white space from around the values
  mutate(val = trimws(val)) %>% 
  # pivot back to wider based on "var"
  pivot_wider(names_from="var", values_from="val") %>% 
  # remove the variables that we created. 
  select(-c(obs, num))

# # A tibble: 15 x 3
#   Dates      V_1   V_2  
#   <chr>      <chr> <chr>
# 1 29/11/2020 48.2  3.07 
# 2 29/11/2020 45.9  3.01 
# 3 29/11/2020 48.2  3.00 
# 4 20/11/2020 47.1  3.04 
# 5 20/11/2020 46.5  3.00 
# 6 20/11/2020 45.8  3.00
```

---

**EDIT: Modified to use GitHub Data Link**

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
Test <- rio::import("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/michaeldavies64/Test_data/main/Test_Data.csv") %>% 
    setNames(., c("obs", "Dates", "V_1.0", "V_1.1", "V_1.2", "V_2.0", "V_2.1", "V_2.2")) %>% 
    filter(obs >= 3)

Test %>% 
    # pivot the data to long-form from wide-form.  The names_pattern argument
    # tells it to search for two things separated by a period and to split
    # that into two variables named "var" and "num". 
    pivot_longer(-c(Dates, obs), names_pattern="(.*)\\.(.*)", names_to=c("var", "num"), values_to="val") %>% 
    # trim the white space from around the values
    mutate(val = trimws(val)) %>% 
    # pivot back to wider based on "var"
    pivot_wider(names_from="var", values_from="val") %>% 
    # remove the variables that we created. 
    select(-c(obs, num))
# # A tibble: 15 x 3
#   Dates      V_1   V_2  
#   <chr>      <chr> <chr>
# 1 29/11/2020 46.4  3.00 
# 2 29/11/2020 46.2  3.00 
# 3 29/11/2020 46.4  3.01 
# 4 29/11/2020 48.2  3.07 
# 5 29/11/2020 45.9  3.01 
# 6 29/11/2020 48.2  3.00
```

Comment: Hi Dave, thanks for your help. I am getting the below error on the last line:

Error in get(nm, envir = fn, mode = "function") : 
  object 'pivot_wider' of mode 'function' was not found

Comment: @MichaelD what do you get if you run the function up through the `mutate(val=trimws(val))` command?

Comment: Sorry Dave, I think the above was because I hadn't loaded tidyr. Re-ran after that realisation and came with the below error:
Error: Column names `V_1`, `V_1`, `V_2`, and `V_2` must not be duplicated.

Comment: @MichaelD I don't see an error in your comment.

Comment: added a GitHub link. Does this change your suggestion?

Comment: @MichaelD I edited my answer to use exactly the data from the GitHub link.